# Bamboo vs CxxTest

Tags: bamboo

When I create a plan in Bamboo and add a task for running CxxTest test code(running `function TS_ASSERT(1==1)` or `st`). When I try to run for checking failure `(TS_ASSERT(1==2))`, this test case is fail and Bamboo output a log as:

```
12-Mar-2014 15:12:07    Failed 1 and Skipped 0 of 2 tests
12-Mar-2014 15:12:07    Success rate: 50%
12-Mar-2014 15:12:07    Failing task since return code was 1 while expected 0
```

So, does anyone here know why bamboo can understand the test result, and what is the return code here(return code was 1 while expected 0)?

Answer (score 0):

From my observation, one windows, Bamboo consider value of the `%ERRORLEVEL%` as the result of the task. so `return code was 1 while expected 0` means your task is returning 1 and Bamboo is expecting 0. Yes, it's expecting 0 since it considers any value other than 0 as failure.